# How can I increment a database value in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm facing a problem with a voting system specially in the vote up feature.

How can I make something like votes++ in the database without the need to select the last votes in single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET voteCol = voteCol + 1
  WHERE id = idOfInterest;
```